# Using mRender with two data variables in jquery Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have several columns defined using datatables. I assign "mData" which I manipulate mRender to display. However, I would like to display two data variables in one column in order to create a link, something like this:

```
    {"mData": "foo",
     "mData2": "bar",
     "mRender": function(data, data2){
          return '<a href="/data/' + data + '">bar</a>'; //
      }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`mRender` function](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#mRender) is passed the data for the whole row.  So, you can access any property you want:

```
{
    mData: "bar",
    mRender: function(data, type, val) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'display':
                return '<a href="/data/' + data.foo + '">' + data.bar + '</a>';
                break;
            // optionally, add case statements for 'sort', 'filter', and 'type'
            default:
                return data.bar;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The data.foo functionality isn't working for me. Even when calling data.bar with bar defined within the column. Is there something else I'm missing? Some setup?

Comment: @BarFooBar - I don't have much to go on.  Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) might help.

Answer (score 2):

```
                'paging': true,
                'sort': true,
                'searching': true,
                'scrollY':70,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '/Home/GetDept',
                    "type": "get",
                    "datatype" :"json"
                },
                "columns": [                         
                     { "data": "city", "autoWidth": true },
                     { "data": "postalcode", "autoWidth": true },
                     { "data": "adress", "autoWidth": true },                      

                     {
                         "data": "deptid",
                         "data": "namedept",
                         "width": "50px", "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {

                             return '<a  href="/Emp/Details?deptid=' + row.deptid + '">' + row.namedept + ' </a>';
                         }
                     }

                ]     
            })
```